# How do I determine parts for my bike and where to source them (new)?

Tags: parts, diy

Do bike shops have specs guides or manuals to know which (eg: integrated headset bearings) parts to use on which bikes? And where do they source said parts (other than from the bike mfr)?

And most importantly: where can the average Joe like myself get this info and buy parts?

The bike I'm currently working on is a 2011 Scott SUB 30, but I can't seem to find any information about specific componentry online. If I were to take it into my LBS I'm sure they'd have no trouble figuring out where to buy, eg, the correct drailleur hanger or headset bearings.

How can I do the same? **Important note: I live in Canada, so would prefer not to pay large import taxes from international sources if possible**

Comment: Did you try calling the manufacturer?

Comment: Don't be so sure your LBS "would have no problem." I've spent many a long bunch of minutes watching a tech flip through the QBP catalog.

Comment: That may be because QBP isn't organized toward a specific part.  While you may know you want a zero stack height headset, there isn't a "zero stack height headset" page.  There is a headset section spread out over ten pages, organized by manufacturer with parts and service items interspersed.  So while you may know exactly what will work, the 13 items QBP has that will work may be spread out on 12 different pages.  Then of course there is price, since the customer wants to know "how much?" you need to start converting the wholesale prices to your shop's prices.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look your bike up online, you should be able to find a stats page that will give you some general specs.  The shops I have been in do not have a "manual" per se of what frames conform to which standards.  It's generally done through experience and visual confirmation/measurement of the bike in front of them.

Derailleur hangers are generally purchased from the manufacturer, but there are some aftermarket ones that will fit specific models of bike.

Bike shops buy parts from a wholesaler (like QBP or J&B).  Most wholesalers won't deal with an individual unless you have a storefront (business) and $X amount of insurance.  You can find businesses online (Colorado Cyclist, Bike Nashbar, Performance Bike) that sell parts online, but realistically you are probably better off buying from your LBS and developing a relationship with them.  Oftentimes, the prices at your LBS will be similar to online without the shipping.

Derailleur hangers are one of the few things that are manufacturer specific.  Most other parts conform to some standard and your average mechanic or shop rat will be able to look at your bike and determine what type you need.

Comment: Not sure where you live but here in New Zealand due to import, distribution and licensing it's cheaper to buy online via websites like Chain Reaction and Wiggle than buy from an LBS. Online prices are in many cases cheaper than wholesale rates for LBSs, especially with free freight.

Comment: That sounds rough.  I live in Alaska, and we get killed on shipping.  NZL probably doesn't have the benefit of having a wholesaler in country.  I don't think import and licensing are problems (unless the kiwi government is taking a big cut) because the majority of items here in the states are imported as well.

Comment: We've got a wholesaler, they just take a large slice which makes it very difficult for LBSs.

Comment: Either that or the LBSs are just pawning MSRP off on the wholesalers. Not sure what it is like there, but when you prodeal here, it is quite apparent everyone is getting their cut.

Comment: @DWGKNZ http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca might be a good option - and they're local to me.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be snarky, but [a quick search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=2011+Scott+SUB+30) turned up a [list of components on the bike](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2011&brand=Scott&model=Sub+30+Men).

Another quick search turned up [the Scott product archive](https://www.scott-sports.com/global/en/support/archive/) (admittedly, not particularly helpful, at least from what I saw), and the [Scott Sports FAQ](https://www.scott-sports.com/global/en/support/faq/), which, in response to the question "Can I get spare parts from SCOTT?" replies: "Yes, SCOTT offers a broad range of spare parts. Please contact your local [SCOTT dealer](https://www.scott-sports.com/dealers/locator/) or the [national distributor](https://www.scott-sports.com/company/distributors/) in case your dealer is unable to help."

Comment: Hi @Zippy, don't get me wrong, I'm a big fan of LMGTFY myself. Always good for a laugh, or to make someone feel stupid. But naturally I did that search well in advance of writing this post, and there's nothing there other than the Bikepedia listing, which is pretty high-level, to say the least. My OP talks about bearing specs and derailleur hanger - both of which are too granular to be on the Bikepedia radar. Scott doesn't, for example, manufacture the bearings, right - so why order them from Scott? The derailleur hanger is made by Wheels Manufacturing for example. Just hoping for alternatives

Comment: When you buy a bike from a company that distributes through brick & mortar dealers, the bike company derives no benefit from undercutting their dealer network. One of my bikes is a Trek, and it is the same with them, though at least in some places their bikes are distributed far more widely than Scott... you buy parts via the dealer. Some dealers, e.g. TrekBicycleStore.com, do sell the parts online, but maybe none of the Scott dealers do. I think you should go to a dealer and ask nicely if you might see a parts list...

Comment: I'm with Tom here, I don't understand why when Scott manufactures very few of their own parts (frames) and re-labels some other OEM parts (saddle, hub, bar and stem) anyone would buy spare parts through a Scott dealer (unless of course this was the cheapest option). The OP is about discovering the specifications so he can make decisions on what parts he would like to purchase. In terms of the frame all you really need to know is that it's a zero stack headset, 68mm English threaded BB, 1'1/8 head tube, 31.6mm seat post and 10x135mm rear drop out. (TBF I got all that from bikepedia)